# Distributed TensorFlow example doesn't work on TensorFlow 0.9

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'm trying out [this tensorflow distributed tutorial](http://shipengfei92.cn/play_distributed_tensorflow/) with the same operating system and python version on my own computer. I create the first script and run it in a terminal, then I open another terminal and run the second script and get the following error:

```
E0629 10:11:01.979187251   15265 tcp_server_posix.c:284]     bind addr=[::]:2222: Address already in use
E0629 10:11:01.979243221   15265 server_chttp2.c:119]        No address added out of total 1 resolved
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "worker0.py", line 7, in <module>
task_index=0)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/server_lib.py", line 142, in __init__
server_def.SerializeToString(), status)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 24, in __exit__
self.gen.next()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors.py", line 450, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InternalError: Could not start gRPC server
```

I get a similar error when trying the [official distributed tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/distributed/index.html).

**Edit:** I tried this on another machine I have with the same packages and now I get the following error log:

```
E0629 11:17:44.500224628   18393 tcp_server_posix.c:284]     bind addr=[::]:2222: Address already in use
E0629 11:17:44.500268362   18393 server_chttp2.c:119]        No address added out of total 1 resolved
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably that you are using the same port number (2222) for both workers. Each port number can only be used by one process on any given host. That's what the error "bind addr=[::]:2222: Address already in use" means.

I'm guessing either you have "localhost:2222" twice in your cluster specification, or you have specified the same task_index to two tasks.

I hope that helps!